# Rails syntax problems in my file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting these errors:

```
/Users/macowner/workspace/blog/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_end end @article = Article.all ^
/Users/macowner/workspace/blog/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
/Users/macowner/workspace/blog/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I know it has to be something simple in my syntax:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end @article = Article.all


    def show
        @article = Article.find(params(:id)
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else render 'new'
    end

    private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should

```
def index
end @article = Article.all
```

be

```
def index
    @article = Article.all
end
```

?

I thought that was a bit weird while I was formatting your post.

Also, missing `end` at the end of your class.  And a missing paren `@article = Article.find(params(:id))`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end @article = Article.all


    def show
        @article = Article.find(params(:id))
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else render 'new'
    end

    private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: Caught 'em all yet? :)

Comment: Not yet. `else render 'new'` doesn't look so hot.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider switching to an editor or IDE that will highlight and help you spot syntactical errors.

Also take a look at the error message. The number after the filename helps you to find the line on which the error occurs.  (It's usually that line or on a line before it.)  For example: `articles_controller.rb:3` indicates that there's an error at or before line 3.  That might make debugging a little easier as you get used to Ruby.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @article = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params(:id))
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```